# How can I capture value from capture function in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem when I want to capture the value using `Capture` function in C#.
My code looks for many patterns in a string, so I use match collection, then for each match I use `Capture` function. But when I want to replace the `captureOut.value` it does not work.

My code:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(string, @"\d*\.*\d+\s")

foreach (Match matchOut in matches)
{
    foreach (Capture captureOut in matchOut.Captures)
    Match match1 = Regex.Match(captureOut.Value, @"\d*\.*\d+");
::::: //}
     output = Regex.Replace(output,captureOut.Value, Function1);
}
// i change the value of pattern based on the output of function 1
```

This part of my code, I do not know why `capture out.value` does not work.

Comment: Could you re-clarify what you are trying to do?  Perhaps provide some examples of input strings and what you would like the result to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the capture property only makes sense if you have groups in your regex, i.e. parts of your regex enclosed in ( ).
Since your regex has no, there is only one captured group and it's the whole string that matches the regex.